# Combine arrays to form a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three arrays:

```
$arr1 = Array (
    [0] => 1001
    [1] => 1007
    [2] => 1006);

$arr2 = Array (
    [0] => frank
    [1] => youi
    [2] => nashua);

$arr3 = Array (
    [0] => getfrankemail
    [1] => getyouiemail
    [2] => getnashuaemail);
```

Is there a way to combine these arrays to get a multidimensional array like this:?

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => 1001
            [1] => frank
            [2] => getfrankemail)
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => 1007
            [1] => youi
            [2] => getyouiemail)
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => 1006
            [1] => nashua
            [2] => getnashuaemail)
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: what you are really looking for is a php version of the [zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) method in ruby/python.

For your specific example [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) works nicely:

```
$result = array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 1001,
    1 => 'frank',
    2 => 'frankemail',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 1007,
    1 => 'youi',
    2 => 'youiemail',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 => 1006,
    1 => 'nashua',
    2 => 'nashuaemail',
  ),
)
```

---

Iterate on the first array (looks like those are ids), and you can match the key for each value to indexes in `$arr2` and `$arr3`

```
$result = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array($value, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key]);
}
```

as @kingkero mentions in his answer, you will get errors if they keys do not exist, which you could check for and ignore any rows where that is the case.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($arr2[$key]) || !isset($arr3[$key])) {
        continue;
    }

    $result[] = array($value, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key]);
}
```

Comment: This would get OP `[ [1001,1007,1006], [frank, youi, nashua], [frankemail, youiemail, nashuaemail] ]` which is not the wanted result

Comment: @kingkero I have edited my answer with a slightly different approach ;)

Comment: @PeteMitchell Wow this solution is perfect. It solved my problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_push($aContainer, $arr1);` or `$aContainer[] = $arr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop in which you access each of the three arrays with the same key.

```
$result = array();
$max = count($arr1);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $result[] = array(
        $arr1[$i],
        $arr2[$i],
        $arr3[$i],
    );
}
```

This could fire an out of bounds exception, since it doesn't check whether or not `$arrX[$i]` exists. Can you be sure that it does?